# php check if date has passed

Tags: php, date

I'm getting dates from a Wordpress field and I need to check if the dates have past or still to come.

```
    $dates = ['date'=>'02/12/13','date'=>'10/12/14','date'=>'14/01/15'];


    foreach ($dates as $date){

        $the_date = $date['date'];


        echo $the_date;

        echo "  ";

        echo date('d/m/y');

        echo "  ";

        if($the_date < date('d/m/y')){
            echo 'gone';
        }else{
            echo 'to come';
        }

    }
```

The foreach echos out this.

```
    02/12/13 22/11/14 gone

    10/12/14 22/11/14 gone

    14/01/15 22/11/14 gone

    27/01/15 22/11/14 to come

    10/02/15 22/11/14 gone
```

It looks like it's just checking the first day date.

Comment: Is it possible to check if the date has passed or not - and how do I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
<?php

$dates = array('02/12/13','10/12/14','14/01/15');

$now = mktime(0,0,0);
foreach($dates as $date) {
  $tmp = explode('/',$date);
  $date_time = mktime(0,0,0,intval($tmp[1]),intval($tmp[0]),intval($tmp[2]));
  echo $date . ' ' . ($now > $date_time?'gone':'to come') . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A better option is to use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class. It allows to compare two DateTime instances using [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).

```
$dates = ['02/12/13','10/12/14','14/01/15'];

foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $the_date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $date);
    $now = new \DateTime();

    echo $date." ".($the_date < $now ? 'gone' : 'to come')."\n";
}
```

The problem you see is because the dates are being compared as strings. The current date is "22/11/14" so it will be *greater* than any other date with a day starting with "1" or "0".

*PD: Your array contains many elements using the same 'date' key. That is a problem so I've removed them in my example.*

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's DateTime API :

```
$date='02/12/13';

if(\DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y',$date) < new \DateTime()){
//date is in the past
}else{
//date is either today or in the future
}
```

Offical PHP doc:

http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use timestamp: Try this:

```
foreach ($dates as $date){

    $the_date = $date['date'];


    echo $the_date;

    echo "  ";

    echo date('d/m/y');

    echo "  ";

    if( strtotime($the_date) < time() )
    {
        echo ' is gone';
    }
    else
    {
        echo ' is to come';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep her simple:

```
// $date is the date you need to compare to today
$date = ("2015 10 03");

// Make sure their formats are purely numeric and match
if ($date->format('m.d.y') >= date('m.d.y'))
{
   your procedure...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using the capabilities of the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class instead. Then you can do the check as follows:

```
<?php
$then = $reset_date;
$then = new DateTime($then);
$now = new DateTime(date("m-d-Y"));
$sinceThen = $then->diff($now);
$new = new DateTime($reset_date);
$old = new DateTime(date("m-d-Y"));

if ( $old->modify('+1 year') < $new) {
    echo "<font color='red'>Reset now <br></font>";
    echo "<font color='orange'>$sinceThen->y years <br></font>";
    echo "<font color='orange'>$sinceThen->m months </font>";
    echo "<font color='orange'>$sinceThen->d days have passed.<br></font>";
} else {
    echo "<font color='green'> $sinceThen->y years <br>
          $sinceThen->m months  $sinceThen->d days till to Reset.</font>";
    //Combined
 }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflowf :-) Code-only responses, with no explanation about why the suggestion solves the problem, are frowned on at StackOverflow. Please read in the Help Center about what kind of Questions and Answers are acceptable, and why. Please add some explanatory text to your answer, or it may end up being removed as "low quality".